# What is the difference between voltage mode control and current mode control for SMPS?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

What is the difference between voltage mode control and current mode control for SMPS? I also wanted to know what kind of modelling techniques are used model these controls (i.e. average models... etc.)?

Comment: It all depends on load what  is more sufficient.

Comment: Not sure why this got closed, there's even an existing answer that adequately covers, at least the first half of the question. The second half is answerable here by way of the first; I would say it would be clearer as a separate question, but I don't mind it either way.

Comment: The reason the post got closed is at the top of the post, a book would be appropriate for this answer, it needs to be simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in how the control loops are configured. An oversimplified picture follows:

In voltage-mode control, the voltage is sensed and compared to a reference, and this difference is applied as the control signal to the converter, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbtLIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In current-mode control, the voltage is still sensed, but this error signal is applied as the input to an inner current-control loop instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcqANv.png)</sup>

The use of this inner current loop improves stability, though it does require additional circuitry to prevent subharmonic oscillation. The improved stability means that many, if not most, modern switching controllers use current-mode control.

(aside: the current measured for current-mode control is usually either the inductor current or the primary switch current, not the output current as shown here. Simplifying the converter to a block labelled "converter" limits my options for positioning the sense resistor.)

Either control method can be modelled by a number of different models, depending on how accurate you need your model to be.